# List type custom settings error

Tags: apex, customsetting

```
public with sharing class CustomSettingsListController {

  public String selectedStage {get;set;}

  public List<selectOption> leadStages {
    get {
      List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
      for (LeadSquared__Change_Lead_Stage_to__c stage : LeadSquared__Change_Lead_Stage_to__c.getAll().values()){
            options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(stage.LeadSquared__Lead_Stage__c)));
      }
      return options;
    }
    set;
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error

> `Constructor not defined: [System.SelectOption].<Constructor>(String)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm): The SelectOption class has two different constructors. One accepts two parameters, the other three parameters.

In your code you instanciate the selectOption with only one parameter.

You have to do:

```
options.add(new SelectOption('YourValue', String.valueOf(stage.LeadSquared__Lead_Stage__c)));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Select option class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) constructor expect two parameter

```
SelectOption option = new SelectOption(value, label);
```

So update you code as shown below.

```
public with sharing class CustomSettingsListController {

  public String selectedStage {get;set;}

  public List<selectOption> leadStages {
    get {
      List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();

        for (LeadSquared__Change_Lead_Stage_to__c stage : LeadSquared__Change_Lead_Stage_to__c.getAll().values()){
        options.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(stage.LeadSquared__Lead_Stage__c),String.valueOf(stage.LeadSquared__Lead_Stage__c)));
        }
      return options;

    }
    set;
  }

}
```